# How do i check how many subscriptions my redis PubSub has on a topic?

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm working on a GQL server (Apollo) with subscriptions and I need to check how many subscriptions there are on a certain topic. The PubSub engine we are using is graphql-redis-subscriptions. I've tried using the following syntax:

```
    const pubSub = // initialize pubSub class here
    await pubSub.subscribe('someTopic',aListener)
    console.log(pubSub.getSubscriber().listenerCount('someTopic'))
    console.log(pubSub.getPublisher().listenerCount('someTopic'))
```

It looks like this should give me the number of active listeners but the result is always 0. I googled a bit but couldn't find any other way of doing this. Kinda hard to provide a minimum working example here as I'd need somewhere to set up a redis server but, hopefully, this is enough info.